AppConfig Feature Flags using HostedConfiguration Construct with Typescript
I have been using this construct HostedConfiguration https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_appconfig.HostedConfiguration.html to create an AppConfig Feature Flags using aws cdk typescript. I have search for some implementation guide but I do not see anything. Can someone provide any helpful link? My initial implementation throws an error Invalid Content during cdk deploy.

Error invoking extension AppConfig Feature Flags Helper: Invalid 'Content' data

I have tried to parse my feature flag json using JSON.stringify but it still encounters the error.
Here is my construct
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import * as appconfig from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-appconfig';
import * as fs from 'fs';

interface AppConfigFeatureFlagsProps {
  applicationName: string;
  environmentName: string;
}

export class AppConfigFeatureFlags extends Construct {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props: AppConfigFeatureFlagsProps) {
  super(scope, id);

  const featureFlagConfigContent = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(props.jsonFilePath, 'utf-8'));

  const app = new appconfig.Application(this, 'MyApp');
  const env = new appconfig.Environment(this, 'MyEnv', {
    application: app,
  });

  const deploymentStrategy = new appconfig.DeploymentStrategy(this, 'MyDeploymentStrategy', {
    rolloutStrategy: appconfig.RolloutStrategy.linear({
    growthFactor: 20,
    deploymentDuration: Duration.minutes(30),
    finalBakeTime: Duration.minutes(30),
   }),
  });

  const hostedConfiguration = new appconfig.HostedConfiguration(this, 'HostedConfiguration', {
    application: app,
    deployTo: [env],
    type: appconfig.ConfigurationType.FEATURE_FLAGS,
    deploymentStrategy: deploymentStrategy,
    validators: [{
       content: JSON.stringify(featureFlagConfigContent),
       type: ValidatorType.JSON_SCHEMA,
    }],
    content: {
      content: JSON.stringify({
                  flags: {
                    flagkey: {
                      name: 'sso_enabled',
                    },
                  },
                  values: {
                    flagkey: {
                      enabled: true,
                    },
                  },
                  version: '1',
      }),
      contentType: 'application/json',
    },
  });
 }
}

my json file is from the aws feature flag json schema, you can find it here.
The content is validated using the JSON schema above.
(1) validate json document
(2) validate json document

You need to describe your specific error and provide the code.

updated my question with specific error and current codes.

Could it be because you don't have a flag with the name "flagkey"?

what do you mean? the flags object is where you specify the constraints and other properties of the flagKey defined inside it then in the values object you define the actual values based on what you define inside the flags object. "flagKey" is just an identifier of the flag property and values.

also in the content I specified the actual values JSON.stringify({
flags: {
flagkey: {
name: 'sso_enabled',
},
},
values: {
flagkey: {
enabled: true,
},
},
version: '1',
})

another content that I used encountering the same error is
{
"flags": {
"isFooFlagEnabled": {
"attributes": {
"percentEnabled": {
"constraints": {
"maximum": 100,
"minimum": 0,
"type": "number"
}
}
},
"name": "isFooFlagEnabled"
}
},
"values": {
"isFooFlagEnabled": {
"percentEnabled": 0,
"enabled": false
}
},
"version": "1"
}

Are you changing the validator as well? What if you omit the validator?

No I'm not. The validator is still the same JSON_SCHEMA as it is given for appconfig feature flags. I tested it using some online schema validator but still I encounter Invalid content same error when I remove the validators in the HostedConfiguration instance.

Try encoding your content with base64. My comment earlier about the name mismatch was incorrect, please disregard.

when I'm encoding the content to base64 the error I encounter is Malformed Content..

I am also running into the similar error. Tried with multiple AWS SDKs using python as well as java. Running in either content data issues or malformed json issues.
String base64EncodedContent = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(updatedContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

CreateHostedConfigurationVersionRequest createHostedConfigRequest = CreateHostedConfigurationVersionRequest.builder().applicationId(APP_ID).configurationProfileId(CONFIG_PROFILE_ID)             .content(SdkBytes.fromByteArray(base64EncodedContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))).contentType("application/json").build();

I ensured the json generated matches with the schema here -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appconfig/latest/userguide/appconfig-type-reference-feature-flags.html
{
    "values":
    {
        "new_feature_flag":
        {
            "attributeValues":
            {
                "dark_mode_support": true
            },
            "enabled": true
        }
    },
    "flags":
    {
        "new_feature_flag":
        {
            "name": "New Feature Flag"
        }
    },
    "version": "4"
}

The base64 encoded content is valid too -> eyJ2YWx1ZXMiOnsibmV3X2ZlYXR1cmVfZmxhZyI6eyJhdHRyaWJ1dGVWYWx1ZXMiOnsiZGFya19tb2RlX3N1cHBvcnQiOnRydWV9LCJlbmFibGVkIjp0cnVlfX0sImZsYWdzIjp7Im5ld19mZWF0dXJlX2ZsYWciOnsibmFtZSI6Ik5ldyBGZWF0dXJlIEZsYWcifX0sInZlcnNpb24iOiI0In0=
software.amazon.awssdk.services.appconfig.model.BadRequestException: Error invoking extension AppConfig Feature Flags Helper: Malformed 'Content' provided (
